# How to populate a dropdown in pug

Tags: each, populate, pug

Switching from handlebars to pug I don't know how to populate a dropdown in pug. In handlebars I could do

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown('set selected', [{{#each trip.tags}}'{{this}}',{{/each}}]);
</script>
```

Anyone got a clue what's the best practice in pug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to generate JavaScript values as part of your template rendering.  The approach you have taken in markdown could cause an XSS attack if `this` is not properly escaped (or it might just cause values like `"` to appear as `&quot;`).

In pug, we recommend using [js-stringify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-stringify) when you need to embed template values in a script.  To do this, you need to install `js-stringify` using npm.  You then need to include it in your locals.  e.g.

```
pug.renderFile('my-template.pug', {stringify: require('js-stringify')});
```

Then you can use it as:

```
script(type='text/javascript').
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown('set selected', !{stringify(trip.tags)});
```

N.B. It is only safe to use the `!{...}` syntax because `js-stringify` properly escapes the values before rendering.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks. Actually, I have set the dropdown from within a AMD module with requirejs after semantic-ui is loaded, and therefore cannot access the variable directly. Is it safe to fill the value in a hidden field and then read it from there? Or what would you recommend in this case?

Comment: I might do an ajax call from within the requirejs module as well I guess... If there is a simpler approach then I would love to know. Thanks!

Comment: Making an AJAX request should be fine.   It would also be fine to put it in a hidden input (providing it is properly escaped).